# Obtener index y string en un combo con javascript o JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy obteniendo los datos desde mysql en un formulario, dentro de los inputs existe un combo llamado sucursal, al traerme el valor no quede el que deberia, como por ejemplo  esta

0- No definido
1- Sucursal 1
2- Sucursal 2

el formulario tiene la sucursal 1 y cuando me traigo los valores siempre queda No definido, ¿como lo hago para que el foco quede en sucursal 1?
les dejo parte de mi codigo;

```js
var url = '../usuarios.php;
$.getJSON(url,  function(data){
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

    var combo = document.getElementById('m_cmb-sucursal');
    combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value = data[i].sucursal;
        
  }

});
```

y una imagen de referencia;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: David hola, sube porfa el codigo de tu drop para saber como tienes definido los value del campo o un json de como llega la informacion que tratas de cargar

Comment: el codigo de como obtengo la informacion esta en la pregunta, solo que deje el combo nada mas

Comment: var url = '../usuarios.php;
$.getJSON(url,  function(data){
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

    var combo = document.getElementById('m_cmb-sucursal');
    combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value = data[i].sucursal;
        
  }

});

Comment: me entrega el valor pero no se como darle el foco al combo para que muestre el nombre

Comment: Hola, sube el código HTML del problema para que podamos ayudarte.